# How to access env file from the root of the Laravel Project?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a **php** script locate at the **root** directory of my laravel project.
I want to access my settings in my .env

---

## I've tried

```
$dbname      = env('DB_DATABASE');
$user        = env('DB_USERNAME');
$host        = env('DB_HOST');
$pass        = env('DB_PASSWORD');
```

---

## I got

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function env()
```

---

What is the workaround for that ? Should I include anything to be able to access `env()`?

Comment: If you are writing a raw php script, you don't have a bootstrapped Laravel environment. No config files have been loaded, no helper functions are available. Might be worth writing your script as an artisan console command instead.

Comment: What is artisan console command ? Do you mind send me a link to that ?

Comment: Here's the very first google search result for "artisan console command" https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan

Comment: It looks complicated for a simple task that I'm trying to do, I'll just use **php** to read from a file using `str_pos()`

Comment: You either need to run it as a console command, or put your code in a route function and then go to that route to execute it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want to load your `.env` config in a separate PHP script, you can do it like this:

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
Dotenv::load(__DIR__);
```

This will load your `.env` config into the `$_ENV` array.

So now you can access your variables like this:

```
$dbname      = $_ENV['DB_DATABASE'];
$user        = $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'];
$host        = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
$pass        = $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'];
```

If you really want that `env()` helper function, just go get that file:

```
require_once "vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php";
```

And now you can also access `env('DB_DATABASE');`

Note: this does NOT give you a bootstrapped Laravel environment at all. It's a simple way to grab your `.env` config variables, but that's it.

Comment: This is more than enough for what I am looking for. :)

Comment: Note that the syntax to create & load `Dotenv` is slightly different across versions.
Version 2.4 would for example need:
    `new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
    $dotenv->load();`
Version 3.x would need:
    `$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
    $dotenv->load();`

See the documentation in the [Github readme](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) for more details. You can easily jump around the version tags there.

Answer (score 5):

Laravel is using [vlucas/phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) to [read the `.env` file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadEnvironmentVariables.php#L27). The [`env()` function is Laravel helper / shortcut](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L437). To use the env command you have to require the vendor files and create an app / kernel laravel object

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

\Dotenv::load($app->environmentPath(), $app->environmentFile());   
var_dump(env('DB_DATABASE'));
```

Comment: Thank-you very much !

Answer (score 1):

This is simple working solution as of **2018** / **Laravel 5.6**

```
//assumes this script is in the root folder, same as .env
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
(new \Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__))->load(); 

$count = $_ENV['UNICORN_COUNT'];
```

Troubleshooting:
 - make sure Dotenv file is correctly called.
 - check the `Dotenv->load()` (and `Dotenv->__constructor()`) and supply the needed params.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that create in laravel 9 doesn't work. The previous answers didn't work for me, though help me to find the following solution:

```
    require_once dirname(__DIR__, 2) . "/vendor/autoload.php";
    $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__, 2));
    $dotenv->load();
    $variable = env('VARIABLE');
```

Answer (score 0):

With newest version of DotEnv, use this to use the `env()` function

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$dotenv = Dotenv::create(__DIR__); // Dir where your .env file is located

$dotenv->load();
```

Comment: What kind of value does `$dotenv->load();` return?!! you should tell him how to get the env value after the last step because that what he is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue for me once fixed by below code

```
require_once dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/vendor/autoload.php";//fetch the document path and removes the public folder using diranme function
$dotenv= Dotenv::create(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));// Dir where your .env file is located
$dotenv=$dotenv->load();
$url=$dotenv["APP_URL"];
```